# how do I fill a html form with fields from my database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a database that is filled using a form, but I wanted to be able to retrieve the fields back and fill in the form so they don't have to retype when editing.

How can I do this using PHP and MySQL?

For example I select all my columns and then I have corresponding text and check boxes on my form in my HTML file after I select them from the database. How would I put them into those boxes?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to render the form with the fields filled in. For example, the "value" attribute is used to specify the initial state of the form element.

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Select all relevant columns from database.
- Echo them into `value` attribute, determine which `option` should be selected, what checkbox should be checked.
- Use `htmlspecialchars()` for `value` attributes.

Comment: well the form is already created so if i echo wouldnt it create a new one?

Comment: im new to this could you give a short example please

Answer (score 0):

First, connect to the database.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Then query the database with an SQL query.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Then pull out the individual data items and echo them where you need.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['firstname'];
echo $row['lastname'];
echo $row['address'];
echo $row['age'];
```

}

Comment: how would i echo them into the form though

Comment: Wherever your form fields are in your code.  
<input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>"/>